Rename my Django auth app to fix the "Application labels aren't unique" error
When I created my Django project I created an app called auth. I never used django.contrib.auth, instead I rolled my own authentication code. A User model without a password field, custom API views and serializes, login goes via magic links sent to email, etc. I didn't use the Django Admin so I never needed Django's auth implementation.
Now I do want to add the Django Admin to my project, and for that I need to add django.contrib.auth and now I am running into some big problems because of the error django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: auth.
Renaming my own auth app doesn't seem possible. I tried to change the label in its AppConfig but existing migrations are breaking in all sorts of fun and exiting ways. So I thought I'd import Django's auth app with a custom label, like so:
# djangoauth.py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class DjangoAuthConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "django.contrib.auth"
    label = "django_auth"

And then I added djangoauth.DjangoAuthConfig to INSTALLED_APPS. But that also doesn't work, as Django's auth app has migrations with the auth name being hardcoded, so changing the app label now breaks those migrations.
I don't really know how to fix this problem. I really wish Django would deal with duplicate app names (just prefix one of them, like django_contrib_auth) but yeah that's not the case. So how can I rename one of these auth apps so that I can use both of them? Without the risk of loosing existing auth data? My app has plenty of users and I really can't have that table be dropped/recreated.
Yes, I have seen How to change the name of a Django app?, but it's an answer from 2011 and I am really hoping that the situation has improved since then 

Unfortunately the question you've linked is pretty much it. Renaming an app is just that complicated, due to how so many things are related to the app name (Which is why it is important to name your Apps carefully).
